# msaccess db field is zero length string but vba isnull() function returns null

Tags: vba, ms-access, null

NULLs again!!!!

I have set a field to zero length string if there is nothing and this applies to about half of the records.
Running the sql statement:

```
select * from contacts WHERE organisation is null
```

return no rows as expected.

But the VBA

```
Debug.Print Len(Me.Organisation)
    If IsNull(Me.Organisation) Then
        Label50.Caption = "null"
    Else
        Label50.Caption = Len(Me.Organisation)
    End If
```

shows all the records with zero length organisation as *null* rather than *0*

The field is defined on the db as short text with the following parameters:

[image]

Why is VBA telling me it is null when it is clearly not?

Comment: I am not able to replicate this issue. What event is code in? Might want to post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically changing property of a control affects ALL instances of control. Use a textbox with expression in ControlSource instead of VBA changing label.

`=IIf(IsNull(Organisation), "Null", Len(Organization))`

Setting a field to allow ZLS does not guarantee field contains ZLS when there is no data. I NEVER allow ZLS in fields.

Comment: Thank you. Still a bit confused. I should have extended my comment after the VBA in my example to say "shows all the records with zero length organisation as null rather than 0 BUT SHOWS THE LENGTH CORRECTLY WHEN NOT ZERO LENGTH". 
I've got round the problem for now but have taken your comment on board for next time.

Comment: Be aware that simply adding a default value to a form only affects *new* records, it has no effect on existing records. You would need to run an update query on all existing records to change them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Debug.Print Len(Me.Organisation)
If  Me.Organisation.text=" " Then
    Label50.Caption = "null"
Else
    Label50.Caption = Len(Me.Organisation)
End If
```